# Smoothstep function

Tags: c++, interpolation, smoothstep

I'm trying to get some results to plot on a graph by using the `Smoothstep` function provided by AMD which was fount on this Wikipedia page [Smoothstep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep). Using the;

> A C/C++ example implementation provided by AMD[4] follows.

```
float smoothstep(float edge0, float edge1, float x)
{
    // Scale, bias and saturate x to 0..1 range
    x = clamp((x - edge0) / (edge1 - edge0), 0.0, 1.0);
    // Evaluate polynomial
    return x*x*(3 - 2 * x);
}
```

The problem is that I am not able to use this method due to the `static method clamp` not being available.

I have imported the following;

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <cmath> 
#include <algorithm>
```

Yet there is no `clamp` method defined.

My maths skill is not the best, but is there a way to implement the `Smoothstep function` just like there is way to implement a `LERP function`;

```
float linearIntepolate(float currentLocation, float Goal, float time){

    return (1 - time) * currentLocation + time * Goal;
}
```

Comment: A clamp function only clamps the first parameter to the interval specified by the second and third, i.e. `clamp(x, a, b)` is simply `x = x<a? a : (x>b ? b : x)` with an additional check ensuring `a<=b`.

Comment: Really? Just go implement clamp.

Comment: @TonyJ as I stated, my maths skills are not the best. But thanks to Thomas's comment, I will be able to.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it was just the namespace "std" which was missing : here is my code that compile :

```
#include <algorithm>

float smoothstep(float edge0, float edge1, float x) {
    // Scale, bias and saturate x to 0..1 range
    x = std::clamp((x - edge0) / (edge1 - edge0), 0.0f, 1.0f);
    // Evaluate polynomial
    return x * x * (3 - 2 * x);
}
```

Comment: Note: this requires C++17.